# Lua gsub second instance

Tags: lua, gsub, lua-patterns

I'm using

```
local mystring = 'Thats a really nice house.'
string.gsub(mystring,"% ", "/",1)
```

to replace the first white space character with an slash.

But how to replace only the second occurrence of the white space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the first instance with something else (assuming the replacement is not present in the string itself, which you can check), then replace it back:

```
print(mystring:gsub("% ", "\1",1):gsub("% ", "/",1):gsub("\1","% ", 1))
```

This prints: `Thats a/really nice house.`. Also, you don't need to escape spaces with `%`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a function as replacement value in `string.gsub` and count the matches yourself:

```
local mystring = "Thats a really nice house."
local cnt = 0
print( string.gsub( mystring, " ", function( m )
  cnt = cnt + 1
  if cnt == 2 then
    return "/"
  end
end ) )
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `string.gsub(mystring,"(.- .-) ", "%1/",1)`.

Comment: @hjpotter92, that is better, yes.